# Finding all prime numbers such that $8p^4-3003$ is also prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Find all the prime numbers $p$  such that $8p^4-3003$ is also a prime

I was trying to solve the previous problem but I haven't been able to. I was thinking about using Fermat's Little Theorem but I'm not sure. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $5\nmid p$, then, by Fermat's Little Theorem, $p^4\equiv1\pmod5$, so $8p^4-3003\equiv \,?\pmod5$.

Comment: I was working $\mod 5$, I almost had it.. anyway..$+1$.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need modular arithmetic to solve this problem, although it may be helpful.

First, notice that $p$ must be $\ge5$, as a prime number by definition is not negative.  Plugging in $5$ gives $1997$, another prime number, satisfying the equation.

Next, notice that a prime number is always odd, and as such will end in $1$, $3$, $5$, $7$ or $9$. Next, notice that $8p^4$ cannot end with the digit $8$, because that number minus $3003$ will end in $5$ and thus not be prime (unless the result is $5$ itself, which cannot happen as $8 \times 5^4 - 3003$ is already $1997$). The result would be divisible by $5$, $1$ and the number itself.

Then consider the digits $1$, $3$, $7$ and $9$ and all numbers ending in these digits raised to the $4$th power.  All will result in a number with the last digit being $1$. That number multiplied by $8$ will be a result that ends in $8$, which will then yield a final result that is not prime. So we know that $p$ is a prime number that ends with the digit $5$.  As already noted, there exists no prime numbers ending in $5$ other than $5$ itself, so this is the only answer.

Comment: looking at the end digit means that you are working modulo 10. So I think it is more or less the same proof idea as in the accepted answer.